# How to call an external url from JSF 2 passing GET parameter generated inside the backing bean

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I have something like this inside a p:dataTable

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myMB.connect}" icon="ui-icon-person" title="Connect" target="_blank">  
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{site.name}" target="#{myMB.siteId}"  />
Connect 
</h:commandLink>
```

connect() calculates a unique ID that I would like to add to the request, like this

```
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
//do some things here with the id
return("./terminal.jsp?id="+id.toString());
```

this fails because id arrives as null at terminal.jsp.

Comment: But do you get the value of id.toString() if you print to the log?

Comment: This url would be inside the iframe of the dialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
return("./terminal.jsp?id="+id.toString());
```

you want

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("./terminal.jsp?id="+id.toString())
```

Returning a String from an action method can only navigate to a page within the current webapp. If you want to navigate to an external webapp you have to use redirect() method of the external context and just return null.

Answer (score 1):

Since JSF 2.0 you have the h:link control to make a get request so you can use in this way:

```
<h:link outcome="terminal.jsp">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{myMB.siteId}" />
</h:link>
```

If you really want to make a get request you can send a redirect to the jsp, you need to change the action method to an action listener so:

```
public void makeRequest(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.sendRedirect("terminal.jsp?id="+id.toString());
}

<h:commandLink actionListener="#{myMB.makeRequest}" icon="ui-icon-person" title="Connect" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must write a simple servlet and use RequestDispatcher. And instead of h:commandLink you can use a h:outputLink. Then:

Create a servlet.

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                 throws ServletException, IOException {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("terminal.jsp");
        request.setParameter("id", id.toString());
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Change the commandLink by

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/myservlet" title="Connect" target="_blank">  
    <f:param name="siteName" value="#{myMB.siteId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```